# ListBox and ComboBox are always empty

Tags: vba, combobox, listbox

I have the following code under a UserForm_Initialize() subroutine for a combo and list box. When I Show the UserForm, both boxes have no items added to them, even though I add them using a With Statement for ease.

```
Private Sub MoneySpinButton_Change()
MoneyTextBox.Text = MoneySpinButton.Value
End Sub
Private Sub ClearButton_Click()
Call DinnerPlanner_Initialize
End Sub
Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub
Private Sub OkButton_Click()

Dim emptyRow As Long

'Make Sheet1 active
Sheet1.Activate

'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Transfer Information
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = NameTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = PhoneTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = CityListBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = DinnerComboBox.Value

If DateCheckBox1.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = DateCheckBox1.Caption
If DateCheckBox2.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = DateCheckBox2.Caption
If DateCheckBox1.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = DateCheckBox3.Caption

If CarOptionButton2.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = "Yes"
Else
    Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = "No"
    
End If
Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = MoneyTextBox.Value

End Sub
Private Sub DinnerPlanner_Initialize()
'Fix Issues with size changes
With DinnerPlanner
.Width = 369.75
.Height = 538.5
End With

'Empty NameTextBox
NameTextBox = ""

'Empty PhoneTextBox
PhoneTextBox = ""

'Empty CityListBox
CityListBox.Clear

'Fill CityListBox
With Me.CityListBox
    .AddItem "San Francisco"
    .AddItem "Oakland"
    .AddItem "Richmond"
End With

'Empty DinnerComboBox
DinnerComboBox.Clear

'Fill DinnerComboBox
With Me.DinnerComboBox
    .AddItem "Italian"
    .AddItem "Chinese"
    .AddItem "Fries and Meat"
End With

'Uncheck Date Check Boxes
DateCheckBox1.Value = False
DateCheckBox2.Value = False
DateCheckBox3.Value = False

'Set no car as default
CarOptionButton2.Value = True

'Empty MoneyTextBox
MoneyTextBox.Value = ""

'Set Focus on NmaeTextBox
NameTextBox.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Why are the list and combo boxes always empty. The methods `AddItem` & `Items.Add` where tried but both fail to show the items?

Comment: It should be `.AddItem` not `.Items.Add`

Comment: Also, remove the parenthesis

Comment: @Simon @braX Hi I have tried with the ```.AddItem``` method and I removed the parentheses. It is the same thing. That's why I was testing code above.

Comment: Please show your full code for the initialize event then as there is no reason it shouldn't work. You left the quotes around the items to add correct? You could also just test with placing a button on the form and just put your code above and only that, on the click event to see if it actually works or not.

Comment: @Simon I have put all the VBA code above. The only thing left is a macro assigned to a button to Show the Userform-I have placed the macro inside the module code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. It's worked for me.
There is no Dinner_Initialize(), becauese Dinner not a UserForm object.
(UserForm here not the same DinnerForm or UserForm1, this is general object).
[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRBEX.png)

```
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'Fix Issues with size changes
Width = 369.75
Height = 538.5

'Empty NameTextBox
NameTextBox = ""

'Empty PhoneTextBox
PhoneTextBox = ""

'Empty CityListBox
CityListBox.Clear

'Fill CityListBox
With CityListBox
    .AddItem "San Francisco"
    .AddItem "Oakland"
    .AddItem "Richmond"
End With

'Empty DinnerComboBox
DinnerCombobox.Clear

'Fill DinnerComboBox
With DinnerCombobox
    .List = Array("Italian", "Chinese", "Fries and Meat") 'your items
    .ListIndex = 0            'default value
    .Style = fmStyleDropDownList 'type of input
End With


'Uncheck Date Check Boxes
DateCheckBox1.Value = False
DateCheckBox2.Value = False
DateCheckBox3.Value = False

'Set no car as default
CarOptionButton2.Value = True

'Empty MoneyTextBox
MoneyTextBox.Value = ""

'Set Focus on NmaeTextBox
NameTextBox.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried the '.List' property and the 'Array' instead of '.AddItems' method but no changes.